# Panel data and selection models issue

Tags: model-selection, econometrics, panel-data

I'm working with a panel dataset, I've used many models,
homogeneous (fixed effect, pooled ols and Driscoll and Kraay)
heterogeneous (swamy random coefficients)  and  would like to do a
post-estimation to select the model that best fit  my regression.
Is there any method, command that may allow me to do this?

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you need a command to do that, you better provide us at least with the language/package you use. Are we talking SAS, SPSS, Stata, SPlus, Minitab, R, ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my experience, model selection is not so much about seeking the model that best fits the regression. The first question to ask is : which model reflects my experimental design the best? The second question would then be : which model reflects the covariance structure in my data the best?

Only then you can start worrying about which model fits the data the best. There are a number of approaches to evaluate and comppare non-nested models. A naive approach would be to do a cross-validation and compare those results. One could eg do a leave-one-out crossvalidation, get the SS values for each run, and treat these SS values as sample data for model comparison.

There's a whole set of literature on comparing non-nested models, but that's always within the same framework. There's little possibilities for comparing models originating from different frameworks other than working with some general loss function.

Comment: Thanks a million for your valuable answer, it really does help, for your previous remark, i'm a stata user.

Comment: In Stata, I wouldn't know a command to check that easily. When using implemented goodness of fit tests, you have to be aware you cannot compare the values across non-nested models in many cases, and definitely not across different frameworks.

Comment: @Ama Maybe worth looking at the UCLA Resources Center for Stata, http://j.mp/9xBk6U

Comment: Joris, Chl, many many thinks to both of you, your advices are really so valuable!!!!